# No module named "Torch"

Tags: python, pip, pytorch, conda

I successfully installed pytorch via conda:

```bash
conda install pytorch-cpu torchvision-cpu -c pytorch
```

I also successfully installed pytorch via pip:

```bash
pip3 install https://download.pytorch.org/whl/cpu/torch-1.0.1-cp36-cp36m-win_amd64.whl
pip3 install torchvision
```

But, it only works in a jupyter notebook. Whenever I try to execute a script from the console, I get the error message:

```
No module named "torch"
```

Comment: when running it from the console, do you first run `source user\anaconda\bin\activate` + `conda activate myenv`?

Comment: when using the scrip could you show us the output of `which python`

Comment: Could someone write dowm how to install pytorch on Windows from source, I don't use conda (Anaconda) at all, because of security reasons. I simply can't download packages/libraries on the fly.

Comment: For anyone here just wanting to install pytorch with pip: `pip install torch`.

Answer (score 96, accepted):

Try to install PyTorch using pip:

First create a Conda environment using:

```
conda create -n env_pytorch python=3.6
```

Activate the environment using:

```
conda activate env_pytorch
```

Now install PyTorch using pip:

```
pip install torchvision
```

<sub>**Note**: This will install both torch and torchvision.</sub>

Now go to Python shell and import using the command:

```
import torch
import torchvision
```

Comment: i have an error: 
ERROR: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement torch==1.4.0 (from torchvision) (from versions: 0.1.2, 0.1.2.post1, 0.1.2.post2)
ERROR: No matching distribution found for torch==1.4.0 (from torchvision)

Comment: Only uninstall python and clean directories, and reinstall with latest python version, and go to https://pytorch.org/   and run command,

Comment: I would say it's definitely bad advice to tell people to uninstall python without knowing what their system is. If that did that on Linux and rebooted before reinstalling python then they are in for a rough time.

Comment: Not sure why `import torch` does not work after running the official conda command: `conda install pytorch torchvision pytorch-cuda=11.7 -c pytorch -c nvidia`. I see `pytorch` in the list of conda modules, but not `torch`. Sometimes `pip` is the only way to get it working :-(.

Answer (score 23):

I installed on my macos by the [official command](https://pytorch.org/get-started/locally/):

```
conda install pytorch torchvision -c pytorch
```

but when I follow the [official verification](https://pytorch.org/get-started/locally/) I get the same problem like yours.

Then I create a conda virtual environment:

```
conda create --name learnpytorch python=3.5
```

and install pytorch inside the environment:

```
conda install pytorch torchvision -c pytorch
```

run the verification, it works.

Hope these could help you.

Answer (score 12):

If you are using **Anaconda Prompt**, there is a simpler way to solve this.

```
conda install -c pytorch pytorch
```

Answer (score 5):

Usually if the torch/tensorflow has been successfully installed, you still cannot import those libraries, the reason is that the python environment you try to import is not the python environment you installed.

For example, if you have installed the torch/tensorflow using `python='/usr/bin/python'`, then you cannot import them to `python='/home/usrname/.../bin/python'`.

The solution is simple thus, just change the python and import again.

Answer (score 5):

Make sure that NumPy and Scipy libraries are installed before installing the torch library that worked for me at least on windows.

1. Install NumPy: `pip install numpy`
2. Install Scipy: `pip install scipy`
3. Go to pytorch.org and select your needs and copy the address
4. Paste the address and download

Answer (score 4):

I had the same problem right after installing pytorch from the console, without closing it and restarting it.
By restarting the console and re-entering my env, I solved the problem

Comment: For my case I had the pytorch installed and the conda venv activated, but for some reason it did not find the module. But after I exited the env and the terminal, and then started everything again including activating the env, it worked.

Answer (score 3):

You need to add this at the very top of your program

```
import torch
```

If this is not a problem execute this program on both Jupiter and command line and pretty much you will understand if you have a mismatch.

```
import sys
print(sys.executable)
```

Answer (score 2):

Switch to `python3` on the notebook

Answer (score 2):

I'm using Jupyter Notebook launching from Anaconda Navigator 2.3.2 (Windows 10) to investigate pyTorch in a new Environment created in  Navigator.  Before launching I added pyTorch via a Command Prompt with the new Environment activated using the following which I got from pytorch.org:

```
conda install pytorch torchvision torchaudio cpuonly -c pytorch
```

I then ran into the *No module named "torch"* issue and spent many hours looking into this. I was eventually able to fix this issue looking at the results of this:

```
import sys
print(sys.path)
```

For me, this showed that the path to site-packages for my kernal (aka Environment) was missing.  So I edited the kernal's kernal.json file found in:

<DRIVE_LETTER>:\Users\<USER_NAME>\AppData\Roaming\jupyter\kernels\<KERNAL_NAME>

To include an `env` section, which adds to `PYTHONPATH` like:

```
{
 "argv": [
  "<ANACONDA_INSTALL_DIR>\\envs\\<KERNAL_NAME>\\python.exe",
  "-m",
  "ipykernel_launcher",
  "-f",
  "{connection_file}"
 ],
    "env": {
    "PYTHONPATH": "..\\..\\..\\Users\\<USER_NAME>\\<ANACONDA_INSTALL_DIR_NAME>\\envs\\<KERNAL_NAME>\\Lib\\site-packages"
},
 "display_name": "<KERNAL_NAME>",
 "language": "python",
 "metadata": {
  "debugger": true
 }
}
```

Please note that in my case I had to go back up 3 directories to the root of the drive, hence, the `..\\..\\..\\` at the start of the `PYTHONPATH` entry.  You might need to change that.  Also if you try to use a full path, to your Environment's site-packages, then it will prepend the current contents of `PYTHONPATH` to it instead of adding it as a separate entity.

Answer (score 1):

Welcome to SO,

please create a seperate [conda environment](https://conda.io/projects/conda/en/latest/user-guide/tasks/manage-environments.html)

activate this environment `conda activate myenv` and than install pytorch in it.

Besides you can check which python you are currently using by `which python`

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem after following the official installation guide in [here](https://pytorch.org/get-started/locally/). I realized that it was my stupid Atom built-in terminal.

Inside the atom terminal, `which python` returned /usr/bin/python, although it showed the mark of (conda_env)$.

I fixed it by opening a new terminal and activating the (conda_env), and it worked. Verified and `which python` yields /Users/my_usr/anaconda3/envs/conda_env/bin/python

Comment: I had a similar weird issue. `which python` shows the conda path. If I run `python` and `import torch` it errors. If I instead run the path from the `which python` command, and run `python` + `import torch`, it suddenly works! Doesn't make any sense to me. This fixed the issue for me: https://github.com/conda/conda/issues/9392#issuecomment-617345019

Answer (score 1):

If you are using windows and you have no CUDA, then go with the following command.

```
pip install torch==1.7.0+cpu torchvision==0.8.1+cpu torchaudio===0.7.0 -f https://download.pytorch.org/whl/torch_stable.html
```

You can visit its official site for more explanation.
[Pytorch Official site](https://pytorch.org/get-started/locally/)

Answer (score 1):

The procedure I used is specific to Windows 10 `PyTorch` installation on `anaconda`.

- Create a conda virtual environment using: `conda create -n torch_env`
- Activate virtual environment using: `conda activate torch_env`
- When I installed, this was my current config: `conda install pytorch torchvision torchaudio cudatoolkit=10.2 -c pytorch`.

Please find correct configuration according to your system settings from pytorch website directly: https://pytorch.org/get-started/locally/

Run `python` with `import torch` command. It should definitely work!

Answer (score 1):

Using Conda on win 10 running script from vs code terminal as:

```
$ script.py
```

Generates error:

```
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'torch'
```

The system goes outside the environment to execute call python.

This works:

```
$ python script.py
```

Answer (score 1):

If you are using conda, it's possible that your console is using a different version of python, and the packages you installed using conda are not installed on this version. In my case, I installed a 3.9 version by downloading from the website, and conda installed a 3.8 version. And all the packages only installed for 3.8. Deleting the 3.9 version did the trick for me.

Answer (score 1):

Most of the answers to this question are unsatisfying in that they explain how to create and activate a conda environment. The reason for the error is however not explained.

In my case, I had a conda environment set up, but the torch module was still not found, even if I installed it.
The reason for the error is that python v2 was the main interpreter, not python3.
You can test that by running `python --version`

Then follow the instructions from above to install the conda environment with the correct python version, e.g.
`conda create -n venv python=3.9`

Answer (score 1):

I had an issue related to the path. Basically if I ran `python` with the path from `which python`, `import torch` works, if I just run `python`, it doesn't work.

[This solution from @shoemakerdr on GitHub worked for me:](https://github.com/conda/conda/issues/9392#issuecomment-617345019)

In your `.bashrc`, **before** the Conda initialize code, put `unset CONDA_SHLVL`

Answer (score 1):

pip3 install --pre torch torchvision torchaudio --extra-index-url https://download.pytorch.org/whl/nightly/cpu

this works in windows, I usually try this command when 'pip install torch' doesn't work.

Answer (score 0):

I am struggling the above answer and it does not work in my case.
That is because I install the porch under window COMMAND PROMPT.

1. Installed under the Anaconda environment command prompt. To do that, type "anaconda" and select the ANACONDA COMMAND PROMPT (this is very important for me to fix my mistake)
2. Do the same command from: https://pytorch.org/get-started/locally/

Answer (score 0):

Check SDK install. you also install the sdk in your environment.

You can install the SDK using navigator.

first, change tab to Environments,

second, push play button of your environment name.

Third, then install SDK.

Answer (score 0):

If you are in the console, and importing a function that uses torch, you may need to add `import torch` within the function to allow for the correct scope. Because if you are importing the function, and there is no import statement at the top of the file, it won't work. Alternatively, make sure `import torch` is at the top of the module with the function you are trying to use, and within console, call the function using: `your_module.function_that_references_torch()`

Answer (score 0):

I tried to fixed the problem both in my laptop and computer, and it was fixed in different ways. You can try.

#### **Laptop(Nvidia GTX 950M)**

I fixed the problem by typing this under the environment that you install pytorch.

```py
$ conda install pytorch torchvision cudatoolkit=10.0 -c pytorch
```

*Remember to change the version(10.0) of you cuda*

#### **Computer(No GPU)**

```
$ conda update -n base -c defaults conda
```

Answer (score 0):

> Blockquote

[image]

in the url: https://pytorch.org/get-started/locally/
are the pyTorch installation instructions
for linux use de command:

**pip3 install torch torchvision torchaudio --index-url https://download.pytorch.org/whl/cu118**

for conda use the command:

**conda install pytorch torchvision torchaudio pytorch-cuda=11.8 -c pytorch -c nvidia**

After executing the installation command, the library is already recognized

[image]

Answer (score -2):

Create the environment:

```
conda create -n env_pytorch python=3.6
```

Install your modules. For example:

```
conda install pytorch torchvision cudatoolkit=10.2 -c pytorch
```

Next time you want to use pytorch:

```
conda activate env_pytorch
```

and when finished:

```
conda deactivate
```