# Pytorch is not found & cannot be installed in pycharm

Tags: python, pycharm, pytorch

I need **pytorch** module to run my project. But When I tried to install it via command prompt via two different ways, it shows an error - [image: Error in cmd installation].

```
C:\Users\Toothless>pip install torchvision --user
Collecting torchvision
Using cached https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/b7/ff /091b4503d5f228bd1120db784e2c071617211b965a8a78018e75750c7199/torchvision-0.3.0-cp37-cp37m-win_amd64.whl
Requirement already satisfied: six in c:\users\toothless\appdata\local\programs\python\python37\lib\site-packages (from torchvision) (1.12.0)
Collecting pillow>=4.1.1 (from torchvision)
Downloading https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/ae/96/6f83deebfcd20a5d4ad35e4e989814a16559d8715741457e670aae1a5a09/Pillow-6.1.0-cp37-cp37m-win_amd64.whl (2.0MB)
 |████████████████████████████████| 2.0MB 27kB/s
Requirement already satisfied: numpy in c:\users\toothless\appdata\local\programs\python\python37\lib\site-packages (from torchvision) (1.17.0)
 Collecting torch>=1.1.0 (from torchvision)
 ERROR: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement torch>=1.1.0 (from torchvision) (from versions: 0.1.2, 0.1.2.post1, 0.1.2.post2)
 ERROR: No matching distribution found for torch>=1.1.0 (from torchvision)

 C:\Users\Toothless>pip3 install torchvision
 Collecting torchvision
 Using cached https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/b7/ff/091b4503d5f228bd1120db784e2c071617211b965a8a78018e75750c7199/torchvision-0.3.0-cp37-cp37m-win_amd64.whl
 Requirement already satisfied: six in c:\users\toothless\appdata\local\programs\python\python37\lib\site-packages (from torchvision) (1.12.0)
 Collecting torch>=1.1.0 (from torchvision)
 ERROR: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement torch>=1.1.0 (from torchvision) (from versions: 0.1.2, 0.1.2.post1, 0.1.2.post2)
 ERROR: No matching distribution found for torch>=1.1.0 (from torchvision)
```

Again I've tried to installed through pycharm [image].

I've been following [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54843067/no-module-named-torch) but conda`` is not listed in my envairoment variable.

Edited: When I tried **pip install torch torchvision --user** this command it gives an error - **ERROR: torchvision 0.3.0 has requirement torch>=1.1.0, but you'll have torch 0.1.2.post2 which is incompatible.**

Edited: I've also tried **pip install torchvision** but it shows with error -

```
C:\Users\Toothless>pip install torchvision
Collecting torchvision
Using cached https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/b7/ff/091b4503d5f228bd1120db784e2c071617211b965a8a78018e75750c7199/torchvision-0.3.0-cp37-cp37m-win_amd64.whl
Collecting torch>=1.1.0 (from torchvision)
ERROR: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement torch>=1.1.0 (from torchvision) (from versions: 0.1.2, 0.1.2.post1, 0.1.2.post2)
ERROR: No matching distribution found for torch>=1.1.0 (from torchvision)
```

What should i do now to make a workable pytorch?

Comment: `pip install conda` for conda

Comment: `torchvision` is a supplemental library for pytorch which includes computer-vision specific functions. You need to install `torch` first. Try `pip install torch torchvision --user`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Finally I've installed my desired pytorch & torchvision. I've installed it via pip.
The commandline I've used to install pytorch:

```
pip3 install https://download.pytorch.org/whl/cpu/torch-1.1.0-cp37-cp37m-win_amd64.whl
```

And for torchVision:

```
pip3 install https://download.pytorch.org/whl/cpu/torchvision-0.3.0-cp37-cp37m-win_amd64.whl
```

I've found this code from [PyTorch](https://pytorch.org/) website.

[image: The requirement I've used]

Answer (score 2):

Check with:

```
pip install torchvision --no-deps
```

It can be because of the dependencies.

Comment: It works fine and torchvision successfully installed but the torch module still is not found.

Comment: ERROR: torchvision 0.3.0 has requirement torch>=1.1.0, but you'll have torch 0.1.2.post2 which is incompatible.

Comment: in my Pycharm project **torchvision** is correctly found but the torch module is still marks as **Unknown Module**.

Answer (score 2):

Before installing, remove old torch and torchvision packages

```
pip3 uninstall torch
pip3 uninstall torchvision
```

As torchvision 0.3.0 requires torch>=1.1.0.

Then you can install torch and torchvision

```
pip3 install torch==1.1.0
pip3 install torchvision==0.3.0
```

Answer (score 1):

`torchvision` is a supplemental library for pytorch which includes computer-vision specific functions. You need to install `torch` first. Try `pip install torch torchvision --user`

Comment: It does not work. it shows - **ERROR: torchvision 0.3.0 has requirement torch>=1.1.0, but you'll have torch 0.1.2.post2 which is incompatible.**

Answer (score 0):

If you are using 32 bit python version this could be the reason. I downloaded 64 bit python and torch installation completed.