# How do I install the d2l library on Windows without conda?

Tags: python, pip, pytorch, d2l

The [d2l.ai](https://d2l.ai) textbook includes its own Python library, `d2l`.  Their [instructions](https://www.d2l.ai/chapter_installation/index.html#installation) recommend installing with `conda`, a Python package manager that also functions as a general library manager.  But I've been burned by `conda` a couple times, and prefer pure `pip`.  How can I install `d2l` on Windows with pure `pip`?  I only need PyTorch, not MxNet or Tensorflow.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Using pip**

This is kind of an embarrassing answer to my own question, but I recommend you follow the [CPU or GPU instructions provided](https://www.d2l.ai/chapter_installation/index.html#installing-the-framework-and-the-d2l-package), following just the `PYTORCH` tab:

```
"C:\Program Files\Python37\Scripts\pip" install torch==1.5.1 torchvision -f https://download.pytorch.org/whl/torch_stable.html
```

and

```
"C:\Program Files\Python37\Scripts\pip" install -U d2l
```

I include the full paths to Python37 here because Python38 is in my path, and `torch`, and therefore `d2l.torch` [only work with 3.5 <= python < 3.8](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58868204/1048186).

Earlier, I had trouble with mxnet being missing, but when I ran `pip install -U d2l` again (with the full path to my prefered Python distribution), `from d2l import torch as d2l` worked just fine for me.

**As standalone script**

Sometimes it is convenient just to use the direct files. For example, for installing with `torch`, you can just save [this file](https://github.com/d2l-ai/d2l-en/blob/master/d2l/torch.py), renaming it to `d2l.py` or `d2l_torch.py` to distinguish it from the main `torch` library. Place it besides your other python script, and then you can import it with `import d2l_torch` or whatever you called the script.

If you read the contents of this python file, you will see it is simply a concatenation of all the code samples in the book, with a few convenience aliases at the end of the file that make it easier for the authors to write their book in three languages at the same time.  You can often get by without importing d2l at all and just copy-paste the example code that you need into your own code (with citation of course), or learn what `torch` commands they are aliasing.

---

### Earlier instructions

In order to import `d2l`, you will need `torch` installed.  Do NOT try to install these with a simple `pip install torch`.  You need specific versions of both libraries for `d2l` to work.

In this example, I use Python 3.7.  These instructions assume that you have another version of Python as your default version and show how to use full paths to `pip` to ensure the right installation.

To install `torch`, go to https://pytorch.org/, in the colorful grid, click on pip, copy the command, open a command prompt as an administrator (right-click and select "Run as Administrator") then paste the command, which should look something like:

`pip install torch===1.5.1 torchvision===0.6.1 -f https://download.pytorch.org/whl/torch_stable.html`

Then, edit the command to replace pip replaced with the full path to your version of pip, e.g.:

`"C:\Program Files\Python37\Scripts\pip" install torch===1.5.1 torchvision===0.6.1 -f https://download.pytorch.org/whl/torch_stable.html`

(You don't need to edit the command as long as Python 3.7 is in your path.)

I expanded [my own answer to a PyTorch-specific question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62614903/1048186) in writing this answer.