# Conda - ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'torch'

Tags: python, anaconda, pytorch, conda

**Steps to reproduce:**

I am using Anaconda on Windows to set up environment for this repo.

`conda create --name pytorch-yolo`

Then I install all dependencies with `conda install --file requirements.txt`

Which returns

```
PackagesNotFoundError: The following packages are not available from current channels:
- torch[version='>=1.2']
```

So I install pytorch with `conda install pytorch torchvision cudatoolkit=10.2 -c pytorch`

When I am trying to evaluate the model from the following repo: https://github.com/eriklindernoren/PyTorch-YOLOv3 with `python3 test.py --weights_path weights/yolov3.weights` inside conda environment, it returns the following error `ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'torch'`

If I run a Jupyter lab or notebook, or even go with python inside conda terminal, torch is easily imported.

**What I've already tried:**

Almost everything from this thread: [No module named "Torch"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54843067/no-module-named-torch)

Specifically, creating a new conda environment with python set to 3.8.2, installing torch to base and then to the environment.

I'm also using pyenv to set global python to 3.8.2, but that doesn't help at all.

`conda list` shows I have pytorch installed

Can't wrap my head around this issue.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are probably using the wrong python binary. Can you try `python test.py --weights_path weights/yolov3.weights`?

I am not familiar with Windows terminal, but you can get the path to the binaries by using the `where` command (`which` for Linux):

```
(pytorch-yolo) C:\Users\RemiChauvenne>where python3
C:\Users\RemiChauvenne\AppData\Local\Microsoft\WindowsApps\python3.exe

(pytorch-yolo) C:\Users\RemiChauvenne>where python
C:\Users\RemiChauvenne\miniconda3\envs\pytorch-yolo\python.exe
C:\Users\RemiChauvenne\AppData\Local\Microsoft\WindowsApps\python.exe
```

We can see that `python3` does not go to the python binary inside the conda environment, whereas `python` is correctly linked to pytorch-yolo.

Comment: Wow, that was pretty obvious but I've spent so much time looking for the answer elsewhere. Thank you. And yeah, I should really switch to Linux already.