# import torch not defined on gcp

Tags: python, torch, google-cloud-dataproc

Trying to run "import torch" on GCP.

I got the message `ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'torch'`

Tried to create a new cluster (through the api, not terminal) with the following properties:

***dataproc->conda.packages->pytorch==1.7.1,visions==0.7.1***

***dataproc->pip.packages->tokenizers==0.10.1,datasets==1.5.0***

The creation of the cluster timed out and was not created.
the same happened even when tried just

***dataproc -> conda.packages -> pytorch==1.7.1***

Trying to conda install on the master manually with the following :

`conda install -c pytorch pytorch`

After more almost an hour, I got :

```
Collecting package metadata (current_repodata.json): done
Solving environment: failed with initial frozen solve. Retrying with flexible solve.
Solving environment: failed with repodata from current_repodata.json, will retry with next repodata source.
Collecting package metadata (repodata.json): done
Solving environment -/
```

Thanks for any help or advice
i.e., except torch I also need :
from transformers import LongformerModel, LongformerTokenizer
from model import RedditModel

Comment: Which dataproc image version are you using ?

Comment: Have you tried anything in here?
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54843067/no-module-named-torch

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You just need to use a newer/latest [PyTorch version available in conda-forge channel](https://anaconda.org/conda-forge/pytorch) (1.8.0 now):

```sh
gcloud dataproc clusters create ${CLUSTER_NAME} \
  --image-version=2.0 \
  --region=${REGION} \
  --properties='^#^dataproc:conda.packages=pytorch==1.8.0,torchvision==0.9.0'
```

Comment: Thank you for your help. It works fine now.

Comment: This helped me install some other library packages as well. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using conda install, try with conda forge. That should work.
https://anaconda.org/conda-forge/pytorch